# Code stops execution abruptly when trying to print a string

Tags: node.js, http, buffer

Whenever I try to print the string, the execution halts and exits the program.

```
var config = require('../config.json');
var upacConfig = config.upac;

var endpoint = upacConfig.endpoint;
var customer = upacConfig.customer;
var port = upacConfig.port;

const http = require('http');
const util = require('util');

module.exports.getAll = function getAll(cb) {
  var url = "/" + upacConfig.methods.all + "?customer=" + customer;
  console.log(url);
  http.request({
    host: endpoint,
    path: url,
    port: port
  }, function(resp) {
    let s = '';
    // console.log('response');
    // var lines = 0;
    resp.on('data', function(d){
      s += d.toString();
      // console.log(++lines);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      console.log(typeof s);
      console.log('length:', s.length);
      console.log(s); //  <-- problem! lines below are not executed...
      console.log('length:', s.length);
      cb(null, s);
    })
  })
  .on('error', e => {
    console.log('Err:', e);
  })
  .end();
};
```

Node version: 7.1.0

All that the code outputs is the follows:

```
/api/v1/all?customer=foo
string
length: 323416
```

Edit: for an MVE do the following:

Here is a simple server which serves a text file that the same number of characters mentioned above. (Mine was JSON string that long...).

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var file = path.join(__dirname,'json.txt')

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is a test client that cosumes what the aboves serves.

```
const http = require('http');

http.request('http://localhost:3000/', r => {
  var s = '';
  r.on('data', d => s+= d)
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('length:', s.length);
      console.log(s);
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: can you insted try `process.stdout.write(s);`

Comment: tried the above...same result :(

Comment: Try `console.log('String: ', s);`

Comment: I've added an mve...which replicates my problem...

Comment: It seems it fails on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `json.txt` 324418 and it worked for me on Windows 10. Could you try attaching windbg and share the call stack?

Comment: inviting you to a dedicated room since I don't know how to use windbg. Lets discuss there further...: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135919/deospace